# How to calculate the error of an function?

Tags: standard-error

I have a function: $$L_R=4*\pi*5*R^2*J$$ I have error values for this R and J. So I want to find the error of $$L_R$$

Should I go for:$$L_R=f$$
$$df=L_{R_{error}}=\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}dx+\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}dy$$ where
$$x=R$$$$y=J$$$$dx=J_{error}$$$$dy=R_{error}$$

However, i have no idea what their coefficients would be or how to calculate the error of $$L_R$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "I have error values for this R and F" - did you mean "R and J"?  Might the errors be correlated?  This issue is known as *propagation of uncertainty* or *propagation of error*

Comment: @Henry yes J is F. Sorry my bad. For instance my J is 5 and R is 8. J_error is 0.2 and R_error is 0.5.

Comment: Or is it just: ΔL = 2 * (ΔR/R) + (ΔJ/J) * L. Where ΔR and ΔJ are errors of R and J, respectively.